# Java or Groovy: loop through hashmap and display html table in Velocity template

Tags: java, html, groovy, hashmap, velocity

DISCLAIMER: Some users cannot read the code comments. This is NOT homework. I am trying to concatenate html and a hashmap. I never did this before. None of the explanations I found out there work. If I use "#" it complains.

Task: using Groovy or Java, display HTML table with HashMap results.
Pseudo Code: please forgive any syntax issues and focus on the `tr` loop

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder; // feel free to suggest another package

def hashmap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
hashmap = {Array1:['a','b','c'], Array2:[1,2,3]};

hashmap.each
{
    a1, a2 -> "${a1}: ${a2}"
    def target = a2['Array2'];

    StringWriter st = new StringWriter();
    def mkup = new MarkupBuilder(st);
    mkup.html
    {
     // Issue: syntax error using "#", I do not now how to concat both objects

        #foreach( $t in $target ) 
        tr
        {
         $t.toString()
        }
        #end
    }

    String desiredOutput = st.toString();
}
```

Desired output:

```
<table>
    <tr>1</tr>
    <tr>2</tr>
    <tr>3</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: and your question is? Please formulate your question by editing that info into the question. BTW... SO is not a homework site, keep that in mind.

Comment: No, it's not homework. Sorry that I did not put a disclaimer "it's not homework." The comment says, "I do not know how to concatenate both objects." I never tried embedding html and and hashmap in a groovy script. I am here to get help on development questions. Please tell me if SO is the wrong place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

- For defining hashmap, it is simple in groovy, no need to use `{..}`
- Assuming that all the entries in map should be shown in the table.

```groovy
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
def hashmap = [Array1:['a','b','c'], Array2:[1,2,3]]
StringWriter st = new StringWriter()
def mkup = new MarkupBuilder(st)
mkup.html {        
   hashmap.collect{ k, vList ->     
        table {
           vList.collect {tr it}
        }
    }    
}
println st.toString()
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/ME1Kx8)</kbd>

Comment: Is it without velocity?

Comment: @user7294900 No idea about velocity. Just groovy. Have you checked the demo link? Is that what you needed?

Comment: @Rao the demo seems to work just perfectly fine. However, I tested output on my project and I am getting iteration one level higher `<tr>Array1</tr><tr>Array2</tr>` I may need a nested iteration.